# Mixpanel on boarding funnel

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

Doing my first implementation with Mixpanel as my analytics tool and just had a generic question I was hoping someone more experienced could help with.

In my onboarding process I use an internal "user_id" to "identify"        mixpanel.identify() 
each person who goes through the process.

The problem that I am currently having is that I do not create a "user_id" until after someone has successfully completed an Oauth login to the company we are integrating with, but I still want to track the number of people that actually clicked on the link I have on my page to attempt to login.

So basically a metric to track the number of people that clicked a certain link, but did not complete our login process.

The problem that I am having right now is that I use the "user_id" as my unique identifying id in mixpanel, so even if I add in the event to the people that click the login link it tracks the event perfectly but it does not tie it to anyone specific, so when I go to create a funnel of the onboarding process the funnel does not properly work because it cannot link the event to any 1 particular person.

Basically I just need my funnel to be able tie the "Click Login" event to a person, who then has their unique key with "identify" created if the user finishes the step following "Click Login"

Has anyone been in a situation like this before? Are there certain features of mixpanel that I do not know about because I am new that could help me out?

If you need me to explain in better detail or do not understand please let me know.

Greatly appreciate any help

Comment: "so when I go to create a funnel of the onboarding process the funnel does not properly work because it cannot link the event to any 1 particular person." - Are you sure this is the case? While the users don't appear in the people analytics they do already have a unique id: "The JS library will automatically issue a distinct_id to each user that loads the library." (https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-do-mixpanels-libraries-assign-distinctid-by-default).

Comment: Otherwise you could assign your own random id and use mixpanel.alias with your registered ID afterwards: https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/using-mixpanel-alias

Comment: Will that "distinct_id" attach itself to the same person once I do "identify" the user in the next step? I will try to mess around with it today to see if that is the case.

Comment: It won't attach to the new person automatically, you need to call mixpanel.alias with your new ID before calling mixpanel.identify.

Comment: So calling mixpanel.alias does not completely replace the Identify? I basically just call mixpanel.alias(my_user_id) and then right after mixpanel.identify(my_user_id)?

Comment: I was wrong actually - just calling mixpanel.alias should be fine. "In situations where you want to link the two IDs (in practice, this really just means when the user signs up) you should use mixpanel.alias instead of mixpanel.identify." - https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript

Comment: Awesome, I seem to have gotten it working on my end. Really appreciate the help.